# Не срабатывает программный клик на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-btn', function () {
    $('#ActionLink').trigger('click');
});
$(document).on('click', '#ActionLink', function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

При нажатии на `#ActionLink` срабатывает `alert('hello')`,а при нажатии на `#submit-btn` нет(не кликается `#ActionLink`, как я предположил). Сам обработчик нажатия на `#submit-btn` точно работает(при написании `alert("text")` выскакивает сообщение text)

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit-btn', function () {
    $('#ActionLink').click();
});
$(document).on('click', '#ActionLink', function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: поздравляю = теперь можешь комментарии писать ...

Comment: Да, Вы ошибаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в вопрос Вашу разметку.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit-btn', function () {
    $('#ActionLink').trigger('click');
});
$(document).on('click', '#ActionLink', function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="ActionLink">Test Link</a>
<button id="submit-btn">Test Button</button>
```